# Suddenly cannot access SSH on LAN

Tags: 12.04, server, ssh, lan, openssh

I had ssh running on my LAN server. Suddenly (not sure what I did), I cannot access the LAN server via ssh. When I try, it just hangs for a while with no response and finally comes out with a timed out message.

> ```
> ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.50 port 22: Connection timed out
> ```

As I recall, maybe I got into some trouble trying to install phpmyadmin and pgmyadmin. Still cannot get that going either but this question is for SSH. I just can't reach my own LAN server from my own desktop.

Not sure if it matters, but I have TWO network cards and one's meant for Internet connection and the other just connects to the LAN.

Any ideas please, on how I can fix this?

EDIT:
Here's the output of my `route` command

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref   Use Iface

default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0     0    eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0     0    eth1
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0     0    eth0
```

Comment: @maggotbrain There's the result of rout. I'm sorry it took long. I had to type this looking at my server screen.

Comment: @maggotbrain yes, I can ping my server from the other LAN PCs. In fact I can ping it on both eth0 and eth1. It's a little hard for me to see how but I can. eth1 is on my network switch and eth0 goes to my 4-port ADSL router. Also eth1 is static.

Comment: Have you verified that the sshd service is running on your server? What is the output of `ps -ef | grep ssh`? Have you tried restarting it with `sudo ssh restart`?

Comment: @maggotbrain I really appreciate you taking time on this. when I tried to restart ssh I got a message like this: **ssh: Could not resolve hostname restart: name or service not known**

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes sense but I tried **netstat -pant** and it listed both eth0 and eth1 as listening on the same port. I thought it may be useful, but not sure.

Comment: @maggotbrain Yes, I can ping the server from itslef using its name. Also I can use http://server-ip/pgmyadmin. Even tried reinstalling ssh server. Nothing seems to respond.

Comment: Could you add the output of `ssh -vvv yourserver`?